# Google cloud KMS rest api to retrieve keyriings

Tags: google-cloud-kms

Is there a rest endpoint to retrieve keyrings at a project level directly in KMS rest appi.
As of now, current API needs keyrings on a per-location basis, I would like to get all keyRings on a specified project id, is there an endpoint. on Google CLoud UI you select a project and it simply lists all keyrings, is there an equivalent at Rest

Answer (score 0):

There are [REST and gRPC APIs for listing Key Rings](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings/list).

```
GET https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/locations/loc/keyRings
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all keyrings in all locations, you need to list the available locations and enumerate the keyrings in each known location. KMS is fully regionalized for reliability reasons, so the service doesn't have APIs which interact with multiple regions.